# Transfer Texture2D via socket in unity

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, unity-game-engine, network-programming

I'm trying to transfer a texture2D in unity using socket. 
I'm facing some serialization problem.

Here is the method tat I use to serialize the texture2D:

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(5, 5); 
    bool loaded = tex.LoadImage(File.ReadAllBytes(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Assets/Textures/IMG_3122.jpg"));
    tex.Apply();

    byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    NetworkWriter writer = new NetworkWriter();
    writer.WriteBytesFull(bytes);
    byte[] data = writer.AsArray();


    byte error;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bufferSize = 1024;

    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    stream.Write(data, 0, 1024);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, data);

    Debug.Log("Send byte : " + connectionId);

    NetworkTransport.Send(socketId, connectionId, myReliableChannelId, buffer, bufferSize, out error);
```

And for the receiver side, here is the code:

```
switch (recNetworkEvent)
    {
        case NetworkEventType.Nothing:
            break;
        case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
            Debug.Log("New Connection event received");
            break;
        case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.Read(recBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

            //deserialize
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            string receivedImgBase64 = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as string;

            //convert received base64 string to bytearray for texture display
            byte[] imgByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(receivedImgBase64);
     }
```

So when I'm trying to read for the `recBuffer` on the receiver side, the stream is null.

The error:

> SerializationException: serializationStream suports seeking, but its length is 0

Is this an error with the serialization process or something else?

Answer (score 0):

[`Stream.Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *reads bytes from the stream and puts them into `recBuffer`*.  But you just allocated the stream, so it's empty - there's nothing to read.

You probably wanted to use [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63z365ty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(recBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
```